# Linking formula and standard cells across columns in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, office365

I have a workbook *W1* which contains a table *W1T1*. One column (by entering the letter 'x') signals, that this row *W1T1Rx* has to be copied into another workbook *W2*.

*W2* contains a table *W2T1* that has some identical columns to *W1T1*. Those columns should automatically be filled (because there is a 'x' in a row somewhere in *W1T1*). **Additionally *W2T1* has columns, where the user inputs custom values, in response to the automatically filled columns.**

I used a combination of INDEX and LARGE functions for the above, which work well.

Now, after the custom information is filled in, Excel should treat the row *W2T1Rx* as linked across columns. Right now, if another row *W1T1Rx* is marked with 'x', depending on the relative position of this row in *W1T1* it will be put somewhere between the other rows *W2T1Rx*, and not necessarily added at the end of *W2T1* (the behavior caused by the function LARGE).

This causes some already existing rows *W2T1Rx* to be moved down, so far without also moving the custom information linked to that row.
Furthermore, removing 'x' in *W1T1Rx* causes the row to be deleted in *W2T1*, subsequently moving rows *W2T1Rx* upwards, again without moving the non-automated cells.

And here is where I am stuck. I need Excel to move the whole row *W2T1Rx*, not just the automatically filled in cells of that row. I want the rows *W2T1Rx* to be linked across columns.

**Any ideas on how to solve this?**

VBA is welcome, though non-VBA is preferred.

Comment: Better you Load the Screen Shot and the Formula use with it. Or you mean to say you have Two Worksheets 2 Tables and Rows begins with X in Table 1 should be copied to Table 2 in Sheet 2 ?

Comment: Screenshot is not possible because of confidentiality reasons. But you are almost right, two worksheets, two tables, if one special column contains 'x', then the entire row should be copied. In the second sheet the copied row gets extended by a few columns, where users input numbers and text.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest the below written Formulas to populate Table 2 in Sheet 
2.*

But let me illustrate the scenario, I've used to test the Formulas.

1. Sheet 1 has Data in Range A2:E50.
2. In Sheet 2 in Cell A1 write **X** (the Criteria).
3. In Sheet 2 in Cell A2 write this Formula and *Drag Down to maximum.*

   **=IF(Sheet1!A2=$A$1,ROW(),"")**
4. Write below written Formula in Cell B2 of Sheet 2.

   **=IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNT($A:$A),"",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,SMALL($A:$A,ROWS($1:1))))**
5. *Drag the Formula till Column E and Down up to maximum Rows.*

**NB:** You find all the records will pulled to Sheet 2 which starts with X in Column A from Sheet 1.

I've suggested to Drag the Formula Down at your maximum because, whenever you insert Rows begins with **X** in Sheet 1 as New Records, will automatically populate the blank Rows in Sheet 2 for both Formulas.

**Note,** *change the Data Range as your need.*

Hope this help you.